# $http POST request only returning one of the values in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-post

I'm creating an app in which one of the views contains a form that should add a post. I'm using the fake [JSONplaceholder API](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com). The resources are not really created on the server but it is faked as if. I'm using console.log to return the title and body of the post I'm creating, but only an ID shows in the console, like so: `Object {id: 101}`

Here's my code:

```
<body layout="column" ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak ng-controller="controller">
    <h1>{{apptitle}}</h1>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="allposts.htm">
        <a href="#addpost">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="singleModel" uib-btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="1" btn-checkbox-false="0">
        Add a post
    </button>
</a>
        View
        <select ng-model="viewby" ng-change="setItemsPerPage(viewby)">
            <option>9</option>
            <option>18</option>
            <option>36</option>
            <option>100</option>
        </select>posts
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="collatedPostList in collatedPosts">
            <div class="onepost col-xs-4 box" ng-repeat="post in collatedPostList">
                 <div class="inner">
                <a href="#post">{{post.title}}</a>
                <hr>
                <p>{{post.body | limitTo: 60}}{{post.body.length < 20 ? '' : '...'}}</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
        <ul uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" class="pagination-sm"
            items-per-page="itemsPerPage" ng-change="pageChanged(currentPage)"></ul>
        </div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="post.htm">
  </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="addpost.htm">
    <form ng-submit="submit()" class="adding">
        <input id="titleadd" type="text" name="title" ng-model="title" placeholder="Add title">
        <br>
        <input id="textadd" type="text" name="body" ng-model="body" placeholder="Add some text">
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" value="Submit">
        Post it
        </button>
        <a href="#allposts">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >
            Go back to post list
        </button></a>
    </form>
  </script>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
Array.prototype.collate = function(collateSize) {
    var collatedList = [];

    if (collateSize <= 0) {
        return [];
    }
    angular.forEach(this, function(item, index) {
        if (index % collateSize === 0) {
            collatedList[Math.floor(index / collateSize)] = [item];
        } else {
            collatedList[Math.floor(index / collateSize)].push(item);
        }
    });

    return collatedList;
};

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'allposts.htm',
        controller: 'PostsController'
    }).when('/post', {
        templateUrl: 'post.htm',
        controller: 'PostController'
    }).when('/addpost', {
        templateUrl: 'addpost.htm',
        controller: 'AddController'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

myApp.controller('PostsController', function($scope) {});

myApp.controller('PostController', function($scope) {});

myApp.controller('AddController', function($scope) {});


myApp.controller('controller', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.apptitle = "Kansi app";
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.posts = response.data;
        $scope.viewby = 9;
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.posts.length;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.viewby;
        $scope.maxSize = 5;
        $scope.collatedPosts = getCollatedPosts($scope.posts);
    });

    $scope.submit = function(){
            $http({
                method:'POST',
                url:"http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
                data : {
                    title: $scope.title,
                    body: $scope.body
                },
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
                .success(function(response){
                    $scope.result = response;
                    console.log($scope.result);
                })
                .error(function(){
                    console.log("error");
                });
        };

    function getCollatedPosts(posts) {
        if (!posts) {
            return [];
        }

        var paginatedPosts = posts.slice((($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage), (($scope.currentPage) * $scope.itemsPerPage));
        return paginatedPosts.collate(3);
    }

    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };

    $scope.setItemsPerPage = function(num) {
        $scope.itemsPerPage = num;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //reset to first page
        $scope.collatedPosts = getCollatedPosts($scope.posts);
    };

    $scope.pageChanged = function(currentPage) {
        $scope.currentPage = currentPage;
        $scope.collatedPosts = getCollatedPosts($scope.posts);
    };
});
```

Network:
[image: Network response]

There are no errors in the console. Why only the id is returning?

Comment: Have you tried to check what comes from the server in network tab? Any way, it is as simple as checking what's being sent and what's being received. It doesn't really concern Angular. Since you haven't provided [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to examine the behaviour, nobody but you can do this.

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Though the screenshot is truncated, it is clearly seen that *Request payload* is empty object. So it doesn't send `title` and `body` fields, it doesn't receive them.

Angular can't just discard `data` object for no reason. It serializes it with `JSON.stringify`. `title` and `body` object properties (equal to `$scope.title` and `$scope.body` respectively) can be omitted on one condition. This happens if they are `undefined`.

Comment: I tried to define them first, but then the form input autocompleted.

Comment: This is a part of more complex issue (the entire application code was posed and it went wrong somewhere). The answer addresses the question directly. This is the reason why you have problems with POST, so you can suppose that $http is fine and narrow down the problem to the form. If you have problems with form, feel free to create a relevant question.